# modal dialog not showing correct information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

this is my action script

**action.js**

```
function showDistrict() { //alert("hello");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dialog_applet.jsp#dialog-modal-district',
        success: function(msg) {
            document.getElementById("dialog-content-district").innerHTML = msg;
        }
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
        $("#dialog-content-district").dialog({
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true
        });
    });
    // alert("hello1");
}

function showCity() { //alert("hello");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dialog_applet.jsp#dialog-modal-city',
        success: function(msg) {
            document.getElementById("dialog-content-city").innerHTML = msg;
        }
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
        $("#dialog-content-city").dialog({
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true
        });
    });
    // alert("hello1");
}​
```

this is my content script which is inside of **dialog_applet.jsp**

```
<div id="dialog-modal-district">

dialog-modal-district is here
</div>
<div id="dialog-modal-city">
dialog-modal-city is here
/applet>
```

on call of any one function **showDistrict()** or **showCity()**. it is showing contents of both `<div>` . But, i want to retrieve the particular `<div>` contents, which has been called. I mean on call of **showDistrict**, it will only show the **dialog-modal-district is here**, but it is showing **dialog-modal-district is here dialog-modal-city is here**

Any help appreciated !!
Thanks in advance. !!

Comment: All this does no totally make sense, can you re-phrase the last part ?

Comment: @DidierGhys my problem is, when i call showDistrict() function, then it's showing the entire contents of the dialog_applet.jsp. which means according to my function, it should only show the contents of the <div id="dialog-modal-district">
dialog-modal-district is here
</div> , because only this <div> has been called from showDistrict() function.. please help me..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now what is the problem.

Unfortunately, using an url `dialog_applet.jsp#dialog-modal-district` will load completely the content of the jsp page, not only the fragment you specify.

You have two options to achieve what you want.

1. **Extract** yourself the actual content you want to insert into the dialogs. The ajax request will load the full jsp page, using the .find() method you can select the part that interests you and only append it to your dialog:

   ```
   success: function(msg) {
       // "msg" is the full jsp page
       $(msg)
           // select the part you want
           .find('#dialog-modal-district')
           // append it to your dialog
           .appendTo($("#dialog-content-district"));
   }
   ```
2. **Use the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** method from jQuery. Its role is to load content from the specified url and it allows to load document fragments *automatically* by using a url syntax a little like the one you tried to use:

   ```
   $("#dialog-content-district")
       .load('dialog_applet.jsp #dialog-modal-district');
   ```

   Note the white-space between the jsp page and the ID selector, this is important to keep it, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Glad it helped. I'm curious though to see the exact content of the "msg" variable because it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, I believe on call of function `showCity()`, you will be getting ajax repsonse as the inner content of both divs, namely,
dialog-modal-district and dialog-modal-city. This is because you are just loading the url dialog_applet.jsp#dialog-modal-city, which will return entire content of dialog_applet.jsp page and not just #dialog-modal-city div content.

You can pass the div name as parameter along with URL, depending upon the URL passed you can generate the ajax response.

Comment: yes, you are right !! but, please can you elaborate the solution for my problem.

Comment: Didier Ghys just gave you the answer